# how do I access a specific key vale within an array of dictionaries

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsarray, nsdictionary

How do I access a single key value from a specific key?

I am using an NSArray of NSDictionary with a plist source as shown below;

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>item name</string>
    <key>level</key>
    <integer>3</integer> // range is 1 .. 7
    <key>Stage1</key>
    <string>Text for Stage 1</string>
    <key>Stage2</key>
    <string>Text for Stage 2</string>
    <key>Stage3</key>
    <string>Text for Stage 3</string>
    <key>Stage4</key>
    <string>Text for Stage 4</string>
    <key>Stage5</key>
    <string>Text for Stage 5</string>
    <key>Stage6</key>
    <string>Text for Stage 6</string>
    <key>Stage7</key>
    <string>Text for Stage 7</string>
</dict>
// more dictionaries follow
```

I can view the whole dictionary by doing the following:

```
NSNumber *helps = [myArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]; 
notesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", helps];
```

Your help is greatly appreciated ... I am such a noob.

Till, thanks for the help!  I was able to add:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [foodArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
notesLabel.text = (@"stage is: %@", [dictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stage]]);
```

Which gives me exactly what I was missing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation on [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - specifically for "objectForKey:"

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [myArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
NSLog(@"name: %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"]);
NSLog(@"level: %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"level"]);
```